# Rice theorem, the proof of the part when the empty language belongs to the property

Tags: turing-machines, rice-theorem

I was going through the classic text "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" by Hofcroft, Ullman and Motwani where I came across the proof the Rice theorem as shown.

$L_u$ => Language accepted by universal turing machine

$P$ => property of a regular language

$L_P$ => set containing the codes of the turing machines which accept those languages in $P$

Theorem : (Rice's Theorem) Every nontrivial property of the RE languages is undecidable.

PROOF: Let $P$ be a nontrivial property of the $RE$ languages. Assume to begin that $\phi$, the empty language, is not in $P$. **we shall return later to the opposite case**. Since $P$ is nontrivial, there must be some nonempty language $L$ that is in $P$ . Let $M_L$ be a $TM$ accepting $L$. We shall reduce $L_u$ to $L_P$, thus proving that $L_P$ is undecidable, since $L_u$ is undecidable. The algorithm to perform the reduction takes as input a pair $(M,w)$ and produces a $TM$ $M'$. The design of $M'$ is suggested by Fig; $L(M')$ is $\phi$ if $M$ does not accept $w$, and $L(M')$ = $L$ if $M$ accepts $w$.

[image: Construction of M' for the proof of Rice's Theorem]

$M'$ is a two-tape $TM$. One tape is used to simulate $M$ on $w$. Remember that the algorithm performing the reduction is given $M$ and $w$ as input, and can use this input in designing the transitions of $M'$. Thus, the simulation of $M$ on $w$ is "built into" $M'$; the latter $TM$ does not have to read the transitions of $M$ on a tape of its own. The other tape of $M'$ is used to simulate $M_L$ on the input $x$ to $M'$ , if necessary. Again, the transitions of $ML$ are known to the reduction algorithm and may be "built into" the transitions of $M'$ . The $TM$ $M'$ is constructed to do the following:

1. Simulate $M$ on input $w$. Note that $w$ is not the input to $M'$ rather, $M'$ writes $M$ and $w$ onto one of its tapes and simulates the universal $TM$ $U$ on that pair. If $M$ does not accept $w$, then $M'$ does nothing else. $M'$ never accepts its own input, $x$, so $L(M') = \phi$. Since we assume $\phi$ is not in property $P$ , that means the code for $M'$ is not in $L_P$ .
2. If $M$ does not accept $w$, then $M'$ does nothing else. $M'$ never accepts its own input, $x$, so $L(M') =\phi$. Since we assume $\phi$ is not in property $P$ , that means the code for $M'$ is not in $L_P$.
3. If $M$ accepts $w$, then $M'$ begins simulating $M_L$ on its own input $x$. Thus, $M'$ will accept exactly the language $L$. Since $L$ is in $P$ , the code for $M'$ is in $L_P$ .

Constructing $M'$ from $M$ and $w$ can be carried out by an algorithm. Since this algorithm turns $(M,w)$ into an $M'$ that is in $L_P$ if and only if $(M,w)$ is in $L_u$, this algorithm is a reduction of $L_u$ to $L_P$ , and proves that the property $P$ is undecidable.

**We are not quite done. We need to consider the case where $\phi$ is in $P$ . If so, consider the complement property $\overline P$ , the set of $RE$ languages that do not have property $P$ . By the foregoing, $\overline P$ is undecidable. However, since every $TM$ accepts an $RE$ language, $\overline {L_P}$ , the set of (codes for) Turing machines that do not accept a language in P is the same as $L_{\overline P}$ , the set of TM's that accept a language in $\overline P$ . Suppose $L_P$ were decidable. Then so would be $L_\overline{P}$ , because the complement of a recursive language is recursive.**

*I could not understand the last paragraph in bold.*

Comment: Can you focus us on which parts of the paragraph you are having trouble with?

Comment: 1. When $\phi$ is in $P$ why are they considering the complement of the property $P$. How our target of proving $P$ undecidable being achieved by using $\overline P$. 2. what is the connection about saying the facts about $\overline {L_P}$ with our proof? please can you help? If I need to clarify more please do say..

Comment: 1. If a language is decidable then so is its complement. Hence if a language is undecidable then so is its complement. 2. The point is that $\overline{L_P} = L_{\overline{P}}$, and so we can apply point 1.

Comment: 1.They first showed the undecidability of $L_P$ (or $P$ ) when $\phi$ was not in $P$. 2.When $\phi$ is in $P$ we using the previous method show that $\overline P$ or $L_\overline P$ is undecidable.3.Using 2 we need to show that $P$ or $L_P$ is undecidable.4.$P$ & $\overline P$ has RE languages(by definition), set of TM which do not accept languages in $P$ are TM which *accept RE languages not in $P$* (which by definition is $\overline P$) so $\overline{L_P}=L_\overline P$ 5.If $L_P$ is undecidable then so is $\overline{L_P}(=L_\overline P)$ which is true. So $L_P$ - hence $P$ are undecidable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Did I get the thing correctly? Or there is some flaw? please do say.

Comment: Yes, that’s the general idea.